# Is there any way to run ssh command on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, ssh, ssh-keys

I want to run the below **ssh command** on **Heroku** if possible?

```
ssh -i "key.pem" user@host
```

Comment: You're probably looking for [`heroku run bash`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos), but it's important to note that this spins up a *new, isolated* instance of your application on a *temporary* dyno. You cannot SSH into the running web dynos. Any installations of software or changes to the filesystem will not affect the application; it's more for "I want to run a database migration" or "I want to test a shell command my app runs" scenarios.

Comment: @ceejayoz while this was true for quite some time (and is actually the better way for many things), heroku now allows ssh into running dynos with [ps:exec](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec), purely for debugging purposes.

Comment: @DenisCornehl Neaaaaaaat! Somehow that slipped by my notice, thanks.